# Getting an error when install PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I tried to install PIL but got error. The error message is:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for PIL.

The versions of my software are:

- Python: 3.6.1
- Pip: 9.0.1
- Django: 1.11.1

Comment: how you tried to install ?

Comment: clearly with pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pillow** and **PIL** cannot co-exist in the same environment. Before installing Pillow, please uninstall PIL and Pillow first.

Then install Pillow with `pip install pillow`

Then make sure code is using `from PIL import Image` rather than `import Image`.

(Many of Pillow’s features require external libraries. Check the [list](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.x/installation.html#external-libraries) and install those also)

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks orvi

Comment: That error is not a result of having both pillow and pil installed.  I do not have pillow installed, and I cannot install PIL.  This also doesn't answer the question of how to install PIL, it only describes how to install pillow